# On the usage of nach / hinter / zu

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning-in-context

In *Der Pfennig* by Hans Eckart, there is also the following sentence:

> Eines Tages war der Vater nach der Arbeit sehr müde.

Except for *nach der Arbeit*, all is clear to me: *One day, father was very tired*.

But what does *nach der Arbeit* mean in this context?

Comment: So, again, it was the temporal, not spatial meaning of _nach_... So simple, and yet so elusive...

Comment: Isn't "nach" usually temporal? The spatial equivalent would be "hinter". "Nach der Schule" vs. "hinter der Schule"...

Comment: @elena: Consider _nach Hause_, _nach oben_  (some dialects use this much more often than standard language) and _nachlaufen_ etc., though of course it is no preposition here.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this context, „nach“ is temporal: he was tired *after* work.

Other meanings of „nach“ include:

- Directionality: „Ich fahre nach Berlin“ (… going *to* Berlin)
- Order in a sequence or chain: „die Fünf kommt nach der Vier“ (*after*)
  also „Bitte nach Ihnen“ (politely asking another person to go first)
- Consequence: „Nach dieser Beobachtung ist das klar“ (*With* this observation it is now clear)
  also „nach Adam Riese“ (following [the works of] Adam Riese)

„Hinter“ is spatial, usually in a two-dimensional sense (as opposed to the more one-dimensional „nach“ in a sequence). A bit like “behind”, as opposed to “after”.

„Zu“ has a number of meanings. But in a directional sense, it is used for people and events, whereas „nach“ is used for places with proper names. „Ich fahre zu der Oma“ or „Ich fahre zu einem Konzert“.

Comment: Very clear and concise. Danke.

Answer (score 0):

Like said, *zu* has a lot of meanings. *Zu* also means **for**, for example:

> Ich esse Gemüse zum Nachtmahl. (I eat salad ***for*** supper.)
>
> Ein Buch zum Lesen. (A book ***for*** reading.)

Comment: This actually does not address the question at all.

Comment: Well, it was aked for *zu*, which was not answered yet.